# Не могу подключиться к БД (Oracle) при помощи JDBC Thin driver

Tags: java, jdbc

Извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, я новичок и только разбираюсь.

Пытаюсь выполнить подключение к БД. 
Использую код из мануала:

```
class JDBCVersion
{
  public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException
  {
    OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:jdbc/jdbc@localhost:1521/XE");
    Connection conn = ods.getConnection();

    // Create Oracle DatabaseMetaData object
    DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

    // gets driver info:
    System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverVersion());
  }
}
```

Не получается:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Ошибка
>   ввода/вывода: Undefined Error     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:384)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:273)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:198)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:176)
>     at JDBC.JDBCVersion.main(JDBCVersion.java:12) Caused by:
>   oracle.net.ns.NetException: Undefined Error   at
>   oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:271)
>     at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:317)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1438)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)    ... 8
>   more

Средствами IDE подключение к базе происходит нормально.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась путём замены региональных настроек перед открытием соединения:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно попробовать таким образом через `DriverManager`. Он сам находит необходимый ему драйвер по виду url.

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String password) {
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", user);
        props.setProperty("password", password);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```